# How to install google chrome to watch netflix in ubuntu?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, browser, netflix

I tried to install google chrome for ubuntu users from my Firefox web browser, but that did'nt work

Comment: How do you try to install it?

Comment: Most of the high-voted and accepted answers won't work out of the box, because of dependencies.

Comment: Please have a look at http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and review your question providing more information.

Comment: @Pilot6 Pandya's answer should work fine, and what your answer suggests is the third answer there.

Comment: @muru That's correct, but can you imagine that a newbie will  check the 3rd answer? They will try 1st and 2nd and fail.

Comment: @Pilot6 why would the second fail? (Or the first, now that GNOME Software supports debs, IIRC?)

Comment: The dependencies will not install and Chrome will not install either.

Comment: @Pilot6 you say that, but I don't see why not.

Comment: I tried lot's of times. After you install once, the dependencies are there and new installs will work. `dpkg` will give an error, `apt install -f` will fix it and install Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Go to google chrome download site

Click on download chrome.

[image]

Click on 64-bit debian/ubuntu

Click on Accept and Install

[image]

By default the application will be downloaded to /home/your-user-name/Downloads. Go to terminal and type

```
cd
sudo su
cd Downloads
apt-get install gdebi
apt-get gdebi google*
reboot
```

Close terminal and click on ubuntu icon on top left side

[image]

Type google and click on the google icon

[image]

The google browser window appears, type your email address and click on next

[image]

Type your password and click on next

[image]

The shown below page opens.

[image]

All done happy experience on google-chrome in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Download the deb file from Google site to your Home folder.

Run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```